# Swing Worker Thread : Inner class vs passing parameter

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes, jtextpane, swingworker

I know SO is for specific questions but I need an advise on what is the correct practice in Java for working with swing worker thread.

My application generates large HTML text in response to a calculation process which is is displayed in a jTextPane. To avoid blocking the GUI I used to do the calculation in a Swing Worker Thread.

My problem is the following to start the calculation I need plenty information available in different menus checkboxes and listbox of the GUI, and at the end of the calculation I need to start functions within the EDT.

Here are 2 possibilities for me :

First one is to send plenty of information to my Swing Worker and also need to pass the MainFrame to access specific functions in the "done()"

```
public class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {      

    private MyMainFrame frame;
    public MyWorker(plenty of params) {
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        //my background process
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
    frame.myfunc1;
    frame.myfunc2;
    frame.myfunc3;
    }
}
```

Second one would be to use a Inner Class

Which one is correct to do in Java. If both are "correct" what are the pros and cons of one against the other.

Comment: Actually, any question that isn't too general to be answered is encouraged here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are OK. The advantage of an inner class is that it has access to the internals of the enclosing object. The disadvantage is that it's not reusable in another context (another frame which would have a similar interface, for example).

Just make sure your code is well structured and readable. For example, you might want to extract the three method calls in your `done()` method in a single method of the frame.

Comment: Thx for the answer. The problem of the code readability is important as my swing worker class is quite large. For the call of the 3 functions, it is 3 distinct functions that I use elsewhere in the EDT. Do you advise me to create another method that regroup the 3 functions and call only that single method. If yes, why is it better that simply calling the 3 functions ?

Comment: It's not fundamentally better. But if the end result of your swing worker is to call these three methods, it probably means that they constitute some sort of atomic operation that could be put in its own method.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the large amount of parameters you have to pass in the constructor that is bothering you, you can group those parameters in a container object and just pass the container (e.g. a `MyWorkerContext` class).

I personally would try to avoid passing the UI (elements) itself, but rather pass a model/stream/... which will be updated by the `SwingWorker`, allowing me to refactor the UI later on without having to fiddle with my `SwingWorker` class.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I do not pass the elements, I have understood that. I only pass the state of some checkboxes and menus that define which calculation to perform. Passing parameters is not so complicated just ask for some writing. The problem is more on calling the functions in my "done" which ask me to pass the frame in parameters. That's the main point where I was not sure if it was correct to do so in java.